# Getting distance between horizontal lists

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get distant between my horizontal lists, but I don't know how to do it. I tried with targeting specific list and add padding, but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/L58v1jr2/1/

In this case, I want more distance between **Follow on Facebook** and **Subscribe by RSS**

This is my code:

```
<div id="theheader">  
           <ul id="subscribe">

                <li class="facebook"><a href="#">Follow on Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="rss"><a href="#">Subscribe by RSS</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#theheader ul#subscribe {
        float: right; margin: 22px 0 0 0; list-style: none;
    }
        #theheader ul#subscribe li {
            float: left; margin: 0 0 0 32px;
        }
            #theheader ul#subscribe li a {
                display: block; height: 16px; font: 13px Georgia, Serif; letter-spacing: 2px; color: #eeede6;
                text-decoration: none; padding: 1px 0 0 10px;

            }
            body #theheader .rss li a {
                padding: 1px 0 0 120px;   /*This doesnt work*/
            }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L58v1jr2/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want this:

https://jsfiddle.net/L58v1jr2/4/

I've also simplified your css selectors alot.

Basically all you do is add

```
#subscribe .rss {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

to your css.